# Campos char en una migration laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

Estoy creando una migration en Laravel, y tengo un campo definido así:

```
$table->char('código', 3);
```

El dato código deberá estar formado por tres dígitos, de `000` a `999`, pero no puedo usar un campo numérico, porque los ceros a la izquierda también deben aparecer. Así pues, tengo que usar un campo `char`, pero añadir algún tipo de restricción, de modo que sólo acepte valores formados por, exactamente, tres dígitos.

La cuestión es si esto puedo especificarlo de algún modo en la migration, o en el modelo, o por programación en los controladores que afecten a este campo. Estoy usando el driver de MySQL. Como la migration se refiere, únicamente, a la estructura de la tabla, no veo muy claro que este sea el sitio adecuado para esta restricción.

¿Alguien ha tenido que hacer esto antes?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay ningún parámetro que le permita especificar que desea exactamente tres caracteres, sin embargo, si un usuario ingresará estos códigos y le gustaría forzarlos a que ingresen tres caracteres, simplemente valide la longitud del campo como mínimo de tres caracteres en tu controlador:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    "código" : "min:3"
]);
```

Comment: Si. Se puede validar a mínimo 3 caracteres y máximo también 3. El problema es que tienen que ser tres dígitos. Sabes si se pueden hacer validaciones con expresiones regulares, por ejemplo? Es algo que se me ha ocurrido al ver tu respuesta, pero no sé bien como hacerlo. Gracias.

Comment: Yes of course, just use the regex rule `"regex:/^([0-9]){3,3}$/"` @JoseQuijado